# Can't start Pycharm due to inability to detect graphics settings

Tags: graphics-card, java, fedora, openjdk, pycharm

I just downloaded the PyCharm IDE on my Feodra to play around with Django. I am unable to run it due to some graphics environment problem, which doesn't tell me much. I have downloaded and installed the OpenJDK as mention in Pycharm installation guide.

My graphics card is a GTX 770.

Here is the console output:

```
[root@localhost bin]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
[root@localhost bin]# ./pycharm.sh 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0

Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment
[root@localhost bin]#
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried export DISPLAY=:0.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is seen if no `DISPLAY` var is set, you wouldn't be able to run `xterm` for that reason either. Nothing to do with your graphics card.

Just correct your `DISPLAY` settings and then re-try pycharm.

The `DISPLAY` setting may be missing because you're trying to execute as root instead of your normal userid (assuming you are running X as your userid, not root)? Just a guess...

Comment: where do we set that variable?

Comment: In the shell/terminal where you intend to launch pycharm via cmdline.

Comment: how to correct DISPLAY settings please be elaborate.

Comment: @Deb You can start here https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#q=how+to+export+display

Comment: @Dan Cornilescu, I am sorry, I checked your above link , didn't find anything useful. I am also facing the same problem of can't start pycharm because of unable to detect graphics environment in fedora.

Answer (score 0):

I had the ,Unable to detect grphic settings' issue when I tried to open pycharm remotely.

chmod +x  worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

execute it without sudo or without root account

Comment: Who, what, when, why, and how?